# Maintain session for ESI-included requests

Tags: caching, http-headers, varnish, esi

I'm having trouble setting up Varnish to properly handle session cookie for ESI-included subrequests.

### Background, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Three files: `index.php`, `navigation.php` and `footer.php` combined together using ESI, where first two files are stateful, but only `index.php` is cachable, while `footer.php` is completley stateless.

```
### index.php
<?php

session_start();

header('Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=10');
header('Surrogate-Control: content="ESI/1.0"');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Varnish test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <esi:include src="http://localhost/WWW/navigation.php" />
        <p>Primary content: <?php echo date('r') ?></p>
        <esi:include src="http://localhost/WWW/footer.php" />
    </body>
</html>

### footer.php
<?php

header('Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=20');

?>
<p>Footer: <?php echo date('r') ?></p>

### navigation.php
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

$_SESSION['counter'] += 1;

header('Cache-Control: private');

?>
<p>Navigation: <?php echo $_SESSION['counter'] ?></p>
```

Varnish VCL configuration:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;

        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}
```

### Desired result

I'd like to see `index.php`/`footer.php` loaded from the cache, purged every 10/20 seconds, while `navigation.php` loaded directly from backend server. Of course the very first request to `index.php` cannot be cached as `Set-Cookie` header must be set, however `footer.php` could be loaded from cache from the very begining.

---

How could I achieve that? I'm aware that presence of `Cookie` header in HTTP request causes cache-miss, but I can't simply delete it.

Comment: What is your current result? Is nothing cached? or everything? Is `esi` available? [Check here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html#example-esi-remove-and-esi).

Comment: @byf-ferdy Opsss... it's not at all. When I started writing I've used example from Symfony, but later I decied it only obscured the question and I've decided to use "plain-PHP" example.

Comment: @byf-ferdy Right now `Cookie` header is available on every (sub)request therefore Varnish is not able to cache anything.

Answer (score 1):

Rather a comment than an answer, but to long to fit in one.

The above example lacks of escaping Varnish default VCL [1], Varnish will always append its default logic to your VCL code [2] if you don't avoid it.

In this case you need at least:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";
  return (lookup);
}
```

Varnish also won't cache any response including a Set-Cookie header unless you force it.

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#examples

[2] https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_Basics.html#the-vcl-state-engine

Comment: I'm fully aware that Varnish won't cache backend response if user request contains `Cookie` or `Authorization`, or HTTP method is not safe. I'm looking for a solution to skip/remove session for outter (direct/first) request and sustain session for subrequests.

Comment: Your case is quite similar to one exercise proposed in Varnish Book (https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Content_Composition.html#exercise-enable-esi-and-cookies) The exercise describes necesary steps altought it does not provide the actual code